# Print Data from database in django

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, dynamic-data-display

I want to display data of two joined tables with a foreign key in django ,i have set it all up but it isn't displaying anything , here are my files:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

class Course (models.Model):
Course_name=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=False,blank=False)
course_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
course_idtomatch=models.IntegerField(max_length=2)

def __unicode__(self):
    return smart_unicode(self.Course_name)

class Subjectsnames(models.Model):
subject_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
course=models.ForeignKey(Course)


def List item__unicode__(self):
    return smart_unicode(self.subject_name)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from .models import Subjectsnames
from .models import Course


def Subjects(request):
Subject = Subjectsnames.objects.get(id=id)

subjects_data = {
    "subjects_names":Subject
}

print subjects_data
return render_to_response("code.html",subjects_data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

code.html:

```
<html>

{% for name in Subjectsnames %}
Name:{{name.subject_name}}
Id:{{name.id}}
{% endfor %}

</html>
```

And i have these data in my database:

**Subjectsnames:**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+
| id | subject_name    | course_id |
+----+-----------------+-----------+
|  2 | Organic         |         1 |
|  3 | inorganic       |         1 |
|  4 | thermodynacmics |         2 |
|  5 | vectors         |         2 |
|  6 | trigo           |         3 |
|  7 | algebra         |         3 |
|  8 | relational      |         3 |
|  9 | c++             |         4 |
| 10 | c#              |         4 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+
```

**Course:**

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| Course_name | course_id | course_idtomatch |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| chemistry   |         1 |                1 |
| pyhics      |         2 |                2 |
| maths       |         3 |                3 |
| computers   |         4 |                4 |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
```

**Ignore course_idtomatch**

As much as i know, i might have done something wrong in for loop in code.html.
If anyone knows please help me in solving it, Thanks in advance .

I have updated my views.py something like this :

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext

from django.db import models
from .models import Course
from .models import Subjectsnames

def Subjects(request):
Subject = Subjectsnames.objects.get(id=id)

subjects_data = {
    "subjects_names":Subject
}

print subjects_data
return render_to_response("code.html",subjects_data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))


print Subject
```

but now when i run python views.py on terminal i get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "views.py", line 7, in <module>
from .models import Course
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: In python, methods and functions should be lowercase with underscores. Commas and colons should be followed by a whitespace. Assignments should have spaces around the `=`. And, you want to iterate on `subject_names` which is not a queryset but just a single object (`get` method). In your template don't loop, just use `{{subject_names.subject_name}}` etc. Your naming of classes and attributes is a bit funky, also.

Comment: @SteveK no, it isn't compulsory, i have checked all of that and included white spaces and also removed loop from template , but nothing is making any difference ,i am able to use admin panel perfectly fine, i have created admin model there and i am able to input objects and display them. White space isn't compulsory `>>> a=1
>>> print a 
1

Comment: I don't say it's compulsory, it's about coding conventions and code readability. If you look at other python code in StackOverflow, you will see the pattern I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Name:{{subjects_names.subject_name}}
 Id:{{subjects_names.id}}
```

Since you are rendering only one object and not a queryset, you dont need the forloop

And i hope, the id in this line is defined somewhere:

```
Subject = Subjectsnames.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: still not working , no output , even i have used `Subject = Subjectsnames.objects.all` instead of `Subject = Subjectsnames.objects.get(id=id)`

Comment: I didn't get that , can u tell me how ?

Comment: i have updated my views.py , but now while running it i got a new error, i have updated my question, can you please see that?

Comment: Then this error :`File "views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from models import Course
  File "/home/dhruv/Desktop/skillshare/mvp_landing/courses/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Course (models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 92, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: from models import Course

Comment: Yes , then it gave an error :  No module named courses.models

Comment: just a moment, i will install it

Comment: can , i have your skype id , again please?